# How to display drop-down list stored data laravel

Tags: laravel, display

After using my form for creating projects, I can see a list of the created projects ( title(string), code(string), domains (drop-down list), owners (drop-down list). instead of showing the name of the domain or owner selected previously in the drop-down list, I can only see the id. I don't know how to fix that.

here's my migration create_projects_table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pros', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id', true);
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('code');
    $table->integer('domain_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')->on('domains');          
    $table->integer('owner_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('owners');            
    table->timestamps();
  });
}
public function down()
{
      Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
}
```

ProjectController :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
//
 $projects = Project::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
          return view('projects.index',compact('projects'))
           ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
  }
 public function create()
 {
   $domains = Domaine::all('nameDomain', 'id');
   $owners = Owner::all('nameOwner', 'id');
   return view('projects.create', compact('domains', 'owners'));
 }
 public function store(Request $request)
 { 
      $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'code' => 'required',
        'owner_id' => 'required',
        'domain_id' => 'required'
 ]);

 Project::create($request->all());
 return redirect()->route('projects.index') 
                ->with('success','Project created successfully');

 }
 public function show($id)
 {
   $domains = Domain::all('nameDomain', 'id');
   $owners = Owner::all('nameOwner', 'id');
   $project = Project::find($id);
   return view('projects.show',compact('project', 'domains', 'owners'));
 }
```

show.blade.php :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
      <strong>Quartier:</strong>
       {{ $pro->quartier_id }}
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
     <strong>Responsable:</strong>
      {{ $pro->responsable_id }}
  </div>
</div>
```

index.blade.php :

```
<!-- ........ -->
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>code</th>
    <th>domain_id</th>
    <th>owner_id</th>
    <th width="280px">Action</th>
 </tr>
 @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->title }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->code }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->domain_id}}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->owner_id}}</td>


 <!-- ...... -->
```

Project.php :

```
class Pro extends Model
{
//
public $fillable = ['title','code','domain_id', 'owner_id'];
```

}

this is what I got after adding dd($projects);  :

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#285 ▼
#total: 3
#lastPage: 1
#items: Collection {#327 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▶]
}
#perPage: 5
#currentPage: 1
#path: "http://127.0.0.1/Projet_PAC/Projet_PAC/public/pros"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
}
```

and then after adding {{ dd($project->domain) }}  as first line in for each loop

```
Domain {#339 ▼
#table: "domains"
+fillable: array:1 [▼
0 => "domain"
]
#connection: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
#attributes: array:4 [▶]
#original: array:4 [▼
"id" => 2
"nameDomain" => "domaine2"
"created_at" => "2017-02-01 22:55:25"
"updated_at" => "2017-02-01 22:55:25"
]
#relations: []
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#appends: []
#guarded: array:1 [▼
0 => "*"
]
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#casts: []
#touches: []
#observables: []
#with: []
 +exists: true
 +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Comment: can you show what `dd($project)` shows before your return line in index function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you asked me to do, can you please explain it more ?

Comment: after this line `$projects = Project::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);` in your ProjectController add this `dd($projects)` . Then go to your index page on your website. And you should be able to see what the $project contains, and paste it in your question so we can see it.

Comment: please check the post again I edited to add the output I got

Comment: great now add you model Project.php so we can see how your eloquent relationships

Comment: Have you added relationship functions in your project.php like shown in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proper eloquent relationships for the models like:

```
namespace App\Project;

Class Project {
  public function domain() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Domaine');
  }
  public function owner() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner');
  }
}
```

Now in the view, you can use:

```
@foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->title }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->code }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->domain->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->owner->name }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Note: I'm assuming that you have "name" column in your owners and domains table

Please have a look to this:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: yes, I have column name in the tables. I tried what you suggested, but, I got this error  :

ErrorException in 1f60125c79899e814ca59f79fba4340134d63b14.php line 60:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\PC\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: Write this in your view as first line in for each loop: {{ dd($project->domain) }}

Comment: Got it, your column name is nameDomain not name

Comment: So it will be $project->domain->nameDomain in view file

Comment: Also make sure that you are using correct column name for owner

Comment: yes, exactly it's nameDomain and nameOwner, But I got the "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Answer (score 0):

You don't have relations to your other models.
try this:

Your Pro.php model should have this functions:

```
public function domaine() {
    return $this->hasOne(Domaine::class);
}

public function owner() {
    return $this->hasOne(Owner::Class);
}
```

In the view use this:

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->title }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->code }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->domaine->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $project->owner->id }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

(remove the dd($projects) i asked you to add earlier)

Comment: this is exactly what I tried, but it says :

ErrorException in 1f60125c79899e814ca59f79fba4340134d63b14.php line 62:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\PC\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: in your index function try to return this  `return view('projects.index',compact('projects'))`  and remove this part `->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5)` to see if it works, also remove this lin eform your view just to test `<td>{{ ++$i }}</td>`

Comment: still getting same error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I have edited my answer to get the id intead of name in your view maybe its tha name it cant find. try it

Comment: here's what I got :

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'domaines.project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `domaines` where `domaines`.`project_id` = 25 and `domaines`.`project_id` is not null limit 1) (View: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\PC\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: It says that you must have a column `project_id` in your domaines table.

Comment: yes, but i have the opposite. domain_id in projects table

Comment: add this to your dominies migration `$table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('pros');`

Comment: You mean, I should add "project_id" in domains table, instead of adding domain_id in projects table ??